# Postgres - How to Join Tables without duplicates

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, duplicates

I'm working on a project that locally used SQLite, now when moving to PostGres (On Heroku) my query reported an error "r.social must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

The original query is:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT c.name, r.social, c.description, p.price
            FROM cryptomodels_coin c  
            LEFT JOIN cryptomodels_coinprice p
            ON  p.coin_id  =  c.name
            LEFT JOIN cryptomodels_CoinRating r 
            ON r.coin_id = c.name
            GROUP BY c.name
```

Which works fine locally, with one unique row returned for each coin

When I added this to the PostGres environment, it threw the aggregate function error mentioned above - I managed to resolve this by adding all columns to the "Group by" clause, as seen below:

```
   SELECT  DISTINCT c.name, r.social, c.description, p.price
                FROM cryptomodels_coin c  
                LEFT JOIN cryptomodels_coinprice p
                ON  p.coin_id  =  c.name
                LEFT JOIN cryptomodels_CoinRating r 
                ON r.coin_id = c.name
                GROUP BY c.name, r.social, c.description, p.price
```

The issue is that I now have duplicate rows for each coin

I've done a fair bit of reading and tried numerous solutions, some of which throw errors and others still result in duplicate rows, really not sure how to proceed, thank you for any assistance

EDIT for additional information: 
Each coin has numerous prices and numerous ratings, with the cryptomodels_coin table being referenced by the other tables by using it's name as "coin_id" the so three coins for example:

```
Coin table: 
| Name | 
--------
|  0X  |
| XSV  | 
| BTC  |

Price table: 
| Coin_id | Price |
-------------------
| 0X      |  43.2 |
| XSV     |  20.0 |
| BTC     |  99999| 

Rating table:
| Coin_id | Social|
-------------------
| 0X      | 20,000|
| XSV     | 12,000|
| BTC     | 5,0000|
```

EDIT 2:

```
 CREATE TABLE "cryptomodels_coin" (
 "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 "description" text NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE "cryptomodels_coinprice" (
 "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
 "price" real NULL, 
 "coin_id" varchar(200) NOT NULL REFERENCES "cryptomodels_coin" ("name") );

CREATE TABLE "cryptomodels_coinrating" (
 "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
 "social" text NULL, "coin_id" varchar(200) NOT NULL REFERENCES "cryptomodels_coin" ("name"));
```

Added SQLFiddle: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9fcff/1
Thanks!

Comment: can you provide us some test data?

Comment: in the table `cryptomodels_coinrating`, does the column `social` really references to `name` in `cryptomodels_coin`. If so, your data sample is not consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something like this would eliminate duplicates as you wish:

```
SELECT c.name AS name, 
       r.social AS social, 
       c.description AS description, 
       SUM(p.price) AS price
FROM cryptomodels_coin c  
LEFT JOIN cryptomodels_coinprice p ON  p.coin_id  =  c.name
LEFT JOIN cryptomodels_CoinRating r ON r.coin_id = c.name
GROUP BY c.name,r.social,c.description
```

Comment: Hi Jim! Thanks for your response - unfortunately that still brings up duplicates, following your comment i'll also add in more information in the original question

Comment: If you can, also add the create table statements

Comment: Will add those now

Comment: Updated with build statements, thanks - The issue with when I completed your query was that it still required everything to be in the group by statement, so while it worked on Sqlite for unique rows with just c.name, with all of them it still brings up duplicates, so rather confused, Thank you

Comment: Would something like this get closer to what you want? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9fcff/2/0

Comment: YES! That's exactly it! Thank you very much Jim!!! Incredibly grateful!